# How to import basic symbols in java IDEs

Tags: java, string

I am using jGRASP and I want to use this symbol: ≥  in my string statement.

```
System.out.println("symbol for greater or equal then is ≥");
```

but the problem is I cant copy paste the symbol to the IDE. it gives me weird content:

```
PrFont34Bin0BinSub0Frac0Def1Margin0Margin0Jc1Indent1440Lim0Lim1?
```

I can use => but that looks vague for human viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can \u escape them.

```
System.out.println("symbol for greater or equal then is \u2265");
```

Btw, one quick and easy way to get the hex of a symbol if you're copying and pasting is to open http://squarefree.com/shell/shell.html and do something like

```
'≥'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
```

which should print out the hex.  Then pad that to 4 digits and stick `\u` in front.
This works for all non-supplemental unicode characters in java except for quotes and newlines.

Comment: But this won't work if the JGrasp console doesn't support this character set or font. This will likely work though with Swing as can be tested if you send the same String into a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog:       String test = "greater than or equal to is " + "\u2265";
      System.out.println(test);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, test);

Comment: @Hovercraft, I'm horribly ignorant of JGrasp.  But if the problem is writing java code that will pass through an IDE and compiler without character encoding issues, then \u escapes should help.

Comment: As I am too -- I use Eclipse, but my experience with most Java IDE console output has been that they only accept rudimentary character encoding such as standard ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Even in a dialog, you may have a default font with no representation for that character. It might show up on your system, but not on another.